# Generating a quiz in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: elisp

Forgive the "duplicate" question. I'd like to see this solved in Emacs Lisp too, and if I just tagged it for both topics, I probably would have only gotten one answer.   The Emacs answer should be sufficiently different that it's probably worthwhile to have it.

I want to teach myself Spanish and I've got several word lists like
the data show below.  How can I generate a quiz from the data that
looks like this?

```
amarillo?  [ ] blue    [ ] yellow  [ ] gray   [ ] pink
azul?      [ ] red     [ ] blue    [ ] green  [ ] orange
 .
 .
 .
verde?     [  ] purple [ ] gold   [ ] green   [ ] black
```

The idea is to randomly include the answer with 3 randomly chosen
incorrect answers.  Ideally, the incorrect answers would not be too
repetitive.

```
amarillo|yellow
azul|blue
blanco|white
dorado|golden
gris|gray
marrón|brown
naranja|orange
negro|black
oro|gold
púrpura|purple
rojo|red
rosa|pink
verde|green
```

Comment: I voted for it.  How much longer do I need to tag things with elisp and emacs-lisp?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264267/generating-a-quiz-in-common-lisp is the other question he mentions.

If you're keeping your quizzes textual, Emacs Lisp is going to be less verbose for stuff like this just because it has primitives that deal with outputting and manipulating strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I'm assuming that you have the input in a file opened in an Emacs buffer.

```
(defun insert-quiz (a-buffer)
  (interactive "bBuffer name: ")
  (let* ((question-pairs (split-string (with-current-buffer a-buffer (buffer-string))))
         (quiz-answers (mapcar (lambda (x) (cadr (split-string x "|"))) question-pairs)))
    (insert 
     (apply #'concat 
            (mapcar
             (lambda (x)
               (let ((q-pair (split-string x "|")))
                 (make-question (car q-pair) (answers-list quiz-answers (cadr q-pair)))))
             question-pairs)))))
```

insert-quiz is an interactive function that takes a buffer name, and uses the stuff in that buffer to generate a quiz for you, then insert that quiz at point as a side-effect. It calls some smaller functions which I'll explain below.

```
(defun make-question (question answers)
  (apply #'format
         "%-16s[ ] %-16s[ ] %-16s[ ] %-16s[ ] %s \n"
         (append 
          (list (concat question "?"))
          answers)))
```

make-question takes a question and a list of answers, and formats them as one line of the quiz.

```
(defun answers-list (quiz-answers right-answer)
  (replace (n-wrong-answers quiz-answers right-answer)
           (list right-answer)
           :start1 (random 3)))
```

answers-list takes a list of all possible answers in the quiz, and the right answer and uses n-wrong-answers to create a list of four answers, one of which is the correct one.

```
(defun n-wrong-answers (answer-list right-answer &optional answers)
    (if (= 4 (list-length answers))
        answers
      (n-wrong-answers 
       answer-list 
       right-answer 
       (add-to-list 'answers (random-wrong-answer answer-list right-answer)))))
```

n-wrong-answers takes a list of all possible answers in the quiz, and the right answer, then uses random-wrong-answer to return a list of four unique incorrect answers.

```
(defun random-wrong-answer (answer-list right-answer)
  (let ((gen-answer (nth (random (list-length answer-list)) answer-list)))
    (if (and gen-answer (not (string= gen-answer right-answer)))
        gen-answer
        (random-wrong-answer answer-list right-answer))))
```

Finally, at the lowest level, random-wrong-answer takes a list of all possible answers in the quiz, and returns a single wrong answer.

After you load the above functions into Emacs, use M-x insert-quiz and type the name of the buffer you have your input loaded into (you'll get tab completion). It wouldn't be too difficult to change the insert-quiz function so that it takes a filename rather than an open buffer-name.

The input you list above will yield:

```
amarillo?               [ ] yellow          [ ] orange          [ ] gray            [ ] red 
azul?                   [ ] gold            [ ] purple          [ ] blue            [ ] orange 
blanco?                 [ ] pink            [ ] red             [ ] white           [ ] black 
dorado?                 [ ] yellow          [ ] golden          [ ] red             [ ] orange 
gris?                   [ ] red             [ ] pink            [ ] gray            [ ] green 
marrón?                 [ ] brown           [ ] yellow          [ ] white           [ ] golden 
naranja?                [ ] orange          [ ] gold            [ ] black           [ ] golden 
negro?                  [ ] pink            [ ] black           [ ] blue            [ ] white 
oro?                    [ ] red             [ ] gold            [ ] purple          [ ] brown 
púrpura?                [ ] purple          [ ] orange          [ ] gray            [ ] black 
rojo?                   [ ] gray            [ ] red             [ ] black           [ ] pink 
rosa?                   [ ] red             [ ] green           [ ] pink            [ ] yellow 
verde?                  [ ] green           [ ] purple          [ ] red             [ ] brown
```

Hope that helps.